# With Spring Webflow 2, what request parameters, if any, are necessary to trigger "submit" transition from view-state?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-webflow

My view-state to action-state transition does not appear to be happening.  In the following example, I want the view-state to transition to the action-state when the user submits the form.  Pretty basic stuff.  But the `setA()` method does not get called.

In the jsp, does the  `submit input` element need to have a name of "`_`eventId", or "`_`eventId`_`submit", or is no name necessary?  Or is something else wrong?  What is webflow checking against when evaluating the `on` attribute of `transition` element?

```
<flow ... start-state="stateA">
<var name="flowBean" class="demo.webflow.WebFlowBean" />
<view-state id="stateA" view="fooView">
    <transition on="submit" to="changeA" />
</view-state>
<action-state id="changeA">
    <evaluate expression="flowScope.flowBean.setA(requestParameters.value)" />
    ...
</action-state>
```

JSP:

```
<form action="demo.htm" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value='<c:out value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>'/>
<input type="submit" name="????" value="Continue"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I think.  I removed the `action` attribute from my `form`, and now everything works:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
```

I'm guessing that, by having that `action` URL in there, somehow I was restarting the flow with each submit.